# OpenCV closing the arc of a semi circle shaped image

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a semi circle shaped image that I am trying to make into a 120 degree fan shape. The image needs to be squished together between the two edges coming closer together. 
After a lot of searching I've tried both affine and perspective transforms. Neither seemed to give me the results I was looking for.

I am using OpenCV2 and C++

[image: Here is an image showing the way I need the images oriented.]

How can I achieve this effect?

Edit:
Currently I map a rectangular image onto a semi circle. So, it would also be acceptable to map directly onto a 120 degree fan shape. Would that be a better approach? and if so how might I accomplish that?

Comment: should be possible by some kind of polar coordinate interpolation I guess. But unfortunately I dont have time to implement it at...